# Microsoft Access Web App Sharepoint (SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, ms-access-web-app

Hi let me start of with saying I have Zero Experience with SharePoint. I have tons of experience with MS Access and SQL Server.

Normally when i need a Data entry front end i'll go for MS Access, but in this case most (probably all of my users) do no have MS Access so a standard MS Access Desktop App is useless.

I have heard that MS Access Web App can be published on to SharePoint, and then Sharepoint can be shared with our users so that they can enter the data.

Now through doing some reading up. I know that you can create a MS Access Web App through sharepoint then design your forms on MS Access and publish them, and the data will be then stored on to SQL Server of the Sharepoint. I hope I have that correct.

I need to be able to access that data through SSMS infact it will be so much better if I can just create the sharepoint app pointing to my sql server.

It would be really helpful if you could offer some guidance on this.

1. Create MS Access Web app on sharepoint (With data going into another SQL Server)
2. Craete MS Access Web App on SharePoint (With data going to the SharePoint Server) - but in this case I need to be able to access the database, and be able to add triggers and constraints.

This might be a very stupid question, but I have no idea how Web App and SharePoint work and I currently have no access to SharePoint so I cannot test. I am basically researching before going ahead and asking for SharePoint from my company.

Comment: Hey Rck.. Check out business data connectivity service in sharepoint.. It helps to connect other data sources with sharepoint..

Comment: Hi I tried to have a look at Business Data Connectivitiy. I can see that you can connect it to another SQL Server, the views that you get are datasheet views. I am not sure that would be a very user friendly, and also can you edit and add rows using the BDC(External Data Source) method?

I wish I could try it out for myself, but I won't be able to get SharePoint until i've made a business case and know for sure that it will work.

Comment: Hi Rck, I would suggest watching the Access web app presentation I gave at the SharePoint Conference in 2014. It's an hour long presentation but it should provide you a good overview of the architecture and possibilities with using Access web apps. Please note that Access 2013/2016 style web apps are much different than Access 2010 style web databases. You can find my presentation on Microsoft's Channel 9 site here: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/SharePoint-Conference/2014/SPC204

Comment: Thanks.. I'll have a look at it and get back to you. Sorry about the delay in replying.

Comment: We have given up on this as our sharepoint development team has come back and said it can hold data you can edit add delete using forms, but the SQL Server that runs SharePoint is not a standard SQL Server there are limitations on what can be done on it, and our requirement was to have real time replication of the database to our SQL Server, and we've been told thats not possible.